# Not all active storage files being loaded. Ruby on Rails. Production Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a Ruby on Rails application that had previous Active storage files already. Upon an update to the application, files that are not images are no longer able to be loaded (pdfs, dosx, etc.)

The server was setup with a local storage.

I am not for sure if this was caused by the update or if something happened to the files.

Comment: How and where do you deploy your app?

Comment: The app is published to Digital Ocean server (Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) x64) and the app was deployed using Mina

Comment: Did you use `set :shared_dirs` with your storage folder?

Comment: I did not use it. what does setting that do?

Answer (score 0):

As you told in comments the problem is that between releases mina doesn't copy your saved ActiveStorage files

To fix that you need to set up shared folder

Add to your `config/deploy.rb`

```
set :shared_dirs, fetch(:shared_dirs, []).push('storage')
```

It could contain other shared folders already, just add ActiveStorage folder (by default it is `storage`, but you can check it in `config/storage.yml`)

Then copy from release folder to shared folder `storage` folder with files

Next deploy must be successful

Please look directory structure

https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/v0.3.8/Readme.md#directory-structure

Comment: ok but that still does not answer as to why pdfs and other files are now being found. Image files are being found but not the other files

Comment: @JohnCoday may be they were uploaded earlier before last deploy. Do you apply these settings now?

Comment: I do have them applied now, I just have not found the old files

Comment: @JohnCoday it is likely that they are no longer there, because the number of releases is not infinite. By default it is 5. Deleted files can be restored only with special utilities. Check that now ActiveStorage files are stored after new deploy